# Add points to 3D image

Tags: image3d

I have 2D image data set for 3D image.
Since my data is very large, in this question, I use sample data.

```
testdata = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
sl = Image3DSlices[testdata];
```

(The the structure of my own data is same as "sl".)

Now, I want to color certain pixels (in the different color from the "sl" depicting color) of 30th picture in the 2D positions of

```
{{25, 30}, {27, 32}, {26, 31}}
```

100th picture in 2D positions of

```
{ {{63 ;; 65}, {42 ;; 45}}, {150, 70}, {{200 ;; 205}, {230, 234}} }
```

250th picture in 2D positions of

```
{{12, 90}, {100, 180}, {3, 48}, {230, 250}}
```

So I made another 3D data set for depicting spots as

```
SpotdataForEachz = Table[Table[0, 256], 256];
stack = Table[SpotdataForEachz, 256];   

stack[[30]][[25]][[30]] = 1;
stack[[30]][[27]][[32]] = 1;
stack[[30]][[26]][[31]] = 1;

stack[[30]][[63 ;; 65]][[42 ;; 45]] = 1;
stack[[30]][[150]][[70]] = 1;
stack[[30]][[200 ;; 205]][[230 ;; 234]] = 1;

stack[[100]][[12]][[90]] = 1;
stack[[100]][[100]][[180]] = 1;
stack[[100]][[3]][[48]] = 1;
stack[[100]][[230]][[250]] = 1;

stack[[250]][[12]][[90]] = 1;
stack[[250]][[100]][[180]] = 1;
stack[[250]][[3]][[48]] = 1;
stack[[250]][[230]][[250]] = 1;

ima = Image[#] & /@ stack;
```

Then I tried to overlay

```
Overlay[{Image3D[sl], Image3D[im]}]
```

However it didn't work. Also, I think there might be a better way of doing this. Does anyone have nice idea for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly reassign the value of a pixel in an `Image` object using `Part` (`[[ ... ]]`). Instead, use [`ReplacePixelValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePixelValue.html). For instance,  for your first specification you could write:

```
ReplacePixelValue[sl[[30]], {{25, 30}, {27, 32}, {26, 31}} -> 1]
```

To avoid repeated typing, you can wrap it all in a `MapThread` expression, giving it a list of images to be modified, and a corresponding list of modifications for each image. The function being applied to each pair modifies each specified 2D slice in place inside `sl`, leaving th.

```
testdata = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
sl = Image3DSlices[testdata];

MapThread[
 (sl[[#1]] = ReplacePixelValue[sl[[#1]], #2 -> 1]) &,
 {
   (* list of images to modify *)
   {1, 80, 100},
  
   (* list of positions to modify in each image *)
   {
     {{63 ;; 90, 10 ;; 50}, {150, 70}, {230, 234}}, 
     {{25, 30}, {27, 32}, {26, 31}},
     {{12, 90}, {100, 180}, {3, 48}, {230, 250}}
   }
 }
]
```

Finally, you reconstruct a 3D image by feeding the modified list of slices to `Image3D`:

```
Image3D[sl]
```

[image: modified 3D image]

Note that in the code above I changed the list of images so it would work with your sample data (which only contains 110 images). Your list of modifications also contained an inconsistent specification (`{{200 ;; 205}, {230, 234}}`) which I didn't know how to interpret, so I dropped it. Otherwise this should be straightforward to apply to your own image stack.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Oh, your explaination is very clear. I could get the 3D image which I wanted. (I'm sorry for having made mistake in typing. {{200 ;; 205}, {230, 234}} should be {{200 ;; 205}, {230;;234}}.)